# Direct or Indirect Pronoun

Tags: objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos

I know that when the pronoun is used in place of the direct object, we use:

- me
- te
- lo,la
- nos
- los,las

When the pronoun is used in place of the indirect object, we use:

- me
- te
- le
- nos
- les

Therefore if I want to say **I told them** I would say **Yo los dije**. According to google translate, the correct translation is **Yo les dije**.

If **told** is the verb and **them** is the direct object, why is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because "them" is not the direct object. In your case the direct object is omitted because presumably it has been mentioned before: whatever you told them, that's the direct object. Also notice that usually "I told them" is translated "Les dije", the subject pronoun is implicit in the verb form.